# Difference Between "When the Job Succeeds" and "When the Job Completes"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the difference between the job notification options "When the Job Succeeds" and "When the Job Completes".  From the looks of it, I assume "When the Job Completes" option encompasses both job successes and job failures, while "When the Job Succeeds" option encompasses only when the job runs succesfully.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **When the job succeeds** to notify the operator when the job completes successfully.
- **When the job fails** to notify the operator when the job completes unsuccessfully.
- **When the job completes** to notify the operator regardless of completion status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191130.aspx